# How to traverse subfolders and loop through excel files in foreach file enumerator ssis?

Tags: loops, ssis, etl

**Scenario**: I have a main folder which has 5 excel files and two sub-folders. I want to store the data of each excel file in the database. the program runs fine when the **"Traverse Subfolders"** box is uncheck. but when I check the traverse sub-folders box the program crashed.

Errors:

```
[Excel Source [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
[Excel Source [12]] Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
```

Comment: There are a number of reasons for the VS_ISBROKEN error. To help narrow this down answer this question: Which security context are you in? Yours (running local/debug) , sql agent, etc. Next, it sounds like the first file in the root works. To see if there is problem with any of the files in the subs, move them from the subs to root--and execute the package--if it fails, examine the files.

Comment: Sheet1 isn't the name of the tab on the subfolder files. This happens a lot with Manually formatted Excel files for consumption,

Comment: To further note, you are correctly traversing the sub-folder because you are attempting to open the file.